# Why was my custom flag to fix grammar on a locked post declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I opened a custom flag on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) about using regex to parse HTML because the post is locked. The question contains a small error. The last line

> Do I have that right? And more importantly, what do you think?

should be

> Do I have that right? More important, what do you think?

Using "more importantly" is a [common mistake](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/importantly.html). Most of the time, "more importantly" should be replaced by "more important."

I was under the impression that grammatical errors [should be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102228/should-i-approve-spelling-and-grammar-only-suggested-edits):

> I would definitely approve those edits. The general rule is to approve any edit that improves the quality of the affected post. That helps to make the site better overall, and is a worthwhile goal in itself.

Nevertheless, my flag was declined:

[image: picture of custom flag]

Why?

Comment: [Recommended reading](http://gtotd.blogspot.com/2009/08/should-it-be-more-important-or-more.html)

Comment: "it's easily dismissed as picayunish pedantry."

Comment: @AJHenderson A grammar pedant responding to a grammar pedant? This doesn't end well.

Answer (score 13):

Really? You want to change *that* piece of that post? Sure, your edit would be "more correct", but who cares? The post is perfectly understandable without the pedantic grammar correction.

Our moderators are *really* busy. Such a minor and worthless change is not worth their time, energy, or having to read your flag. Please don't flag for stuff like that.

Comment: [Slow clap](http://media0.giphy.com/media/gRxjhVNfFgqI0/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 13):

I declined your flag, for exactly the reason I layout in my flag declination response.

There are lots of problems on Stack Overflow we need your help with:

The Low Quality review Queue.

The New Answers Queue.

The Front Page.

The Close Vote Queue.

Our time as moderators is finite;  We try to maximize the time we spend on important things.  Likewise, please maximize your time on the important parts of the site where we need your help, and not on things that really don't matter.  In this case, a minor grammatical mistake on a locked post.

I could have accepted your flag and done nothing, or accepted your flag and made the change, but I don't want to encourage trivial flags for moderator attention.  That [has led us down dark rabbit holes before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently), and it's not a good idea to go back.

Comment: I think you should compromise with OP.  He should start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/, fix all grammar problems, then move on to 5, 6, etc.  Once he gets to 1732348, unlock it and let him fix that one too.

Comment: @Will DEAL. No backsies, OP.

Comment: On a related note, it could reduce the amount of flags if we were able to vote to delete in the late answer and first post queue, just like we can in the low quality queue.

Comment: This is really sad and worrying. You could have opted for dispute, too, without penalizing the contributor. Naturally, that would carry a meaningful message, too.

Comment: @lpapp moderators get two options: accept or decline. The community can dispute flags, we cannot.

Comment: You can only dispute [at times](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281149/offensive-flag-declined#comment133928_281149)? If so, I think it is a fundamental flaw in the collaboration workflow.

Comment: @lpapp we don't have the option to dispute.

Comment: Why has that never been changed?

Comment: @lpapp sounds like a good meta question to ask. The only difference functionally between a decline and a dispute is that a declination results in loss of flagging ability if there is a high number, whereas a disput doesn't count against the flagger. Of course, moderator handling should resolve disputes.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: go ahead, any question labeled with my name is inherently destined for downvotes to oblivion, so I am not sure it would be a good idea for _me_ to bring it up. Perhaps do not even refer to that you have ever discussed it with me. ^_^

Comment: @lpapp, the dispute/decline handling makes sense to me.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker the loss of flagging ability is a pretty big issue when the only other option is to penalise the poor fella for a post the mod is not quiiite sure needs a -100 rep penalty for. Oh well, we can live with one less flagger, I guess.